# How to create singleton Object like a Angular1 Service?

Tags: angular, angular2-di

I am wondering how can I create singleton object in Angular2, that will hold the value of some attributes throughout life of application - so that I can use it in many components, and inject it.

Any ideas?

Thanks

My attempt was to do:

```
bootstrap(MyApp,[ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
HTTP_PROVIDERS,
provide(LocationStrategy, {useClass: HashLocationStrategy}),
provide(APP_BASE_HREF, {useValue: '/'}),Login])

where 

Login:

@Injectable()
export class Login {
    public  username: string = "any";
    constructor(private _http:Http, private _router:Router){

    }

    public static login(username,password){
        var creds = 'username=' + username+'&password='+password;
        this._http.post('/authentication/login',creds,{headers: contentHeaders})
            .subscribe(
                success =>{
                    this.username = success.json().username;
                    this._router.navigate(['Dashboard']);
            },
                error =>{
                    console.log('Wrong creds')
            });
    }

    public getUsername(){
        return this.username;
    }
}
```

In this case, getUsername() works, but this._http post does not - it throws an error:

ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'post' of undefined
ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:

Comment: have you learned about `sharedService` in `angular2`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

singleton pattern can be achieved through `sharedService`. You have to inject it into `bootstrap` function like

```
bootstrap(AppComponent,[sharedService]); //
```

I have read your updated question. **[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/bygpFVP9DwSq9iaLOBLI?p=preview)** which shares object like you want.

Comment: Can you modify the plunker so that you can inject the http and router into the nameService?

Comment: Yes sure. in few mins.

Comment: Look now. That is what you asked for.

Comment: Now, when I am trying to use http in this service, I get an error: http://plnkr.co/edit/f1ykfoCMrHb5qc153wd8?p=preview

Comment: Check now my answer's link.

Answer (score 1):

Add the service to the providers list in

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [OtherProviders, MySingletonService]);
```

(don't add `MySingletonService` anywhere else to `providers`.

Angular2 DI ensures that the same instance is injected everywhere.

Comment: Can you show me example of how I can construct a service that will take Router and Http as a dependency? I couldn't do it.

Comment: I will edit my answer in a 5', to show how I was trying to achieve this.

Comment: The code in your question is missing a decorator:  `@Injectable() export class MyService(` and in `bootstrap` you need to list the providers `bootstrap(MyApp,[HTTP_PROVIDERS, ROUTER_PROVIDERS, MyService,..])` (these providers need to be imported)

Comment: this still gives me an error of Property '_http' does not exist on type 'typeof MyService'.

Comment: And Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'getOptional' of undefined(…)

Comment: Either you assign it manually to `this._http` like `constructor(_http:Http) { this._http = _http;}` or use the short form `constructor(private _Http:Http, private _Router:Router){}`

Comment: "Still doesn't work" is not very helpful. Do you get an error message. What is working, what is not working? Is anything happening at all?

Comment: You can see this plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/f1ykfoCMrHb5qc153wd8?p=preview Here, When u click change the name button, I have an error.

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined  - which seems like Http is not injeceted;

Comment: You didn't inject `Http` to `NameService` http://plnkr.co/edit/2QPNtJpsvsiX8bCrSDBU?p=preview